# How to add Mac-address in Django framework

Tags: python, django, database, mac-address

**I have a django app that allows user to login but I want to have only one user for one device.After some research getting the mac address of device from which users login and then storing the mac address in database seems to be good logic.How can I do so?Any python packages or so??**

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this information on your host server because MAC address uniquely identifies the running computer so it would be a security vulnerability.

There are more user identification options such as local storage or just cookies.

Comment: It's just my client. He says he wants the mac-address of the Pc running.If any docs or info can you please help me. My deadline is very near

Comment: lol, that's impossible. As a programmer you should understand the limitation. You can  get a lot of money  if you discover such vulnerability from bounty program. If you can get mac address, then you can also execute arbitrary code on client device.